# No error, yet no pdf

Tags: pdf, compiling, editors

This is probably the ultimate beginner-level question, but I can't produce a pdf from LaTeX.

I downloaded from here (http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/) three things:

1)res9a.tex

2)res.cls

3)helvetica.sty

and I saved all three files in the same directory (folder).

I open res9a.tex in Texnicle (http://www.bobsoft-mac.de/texnicle/texnicle.html) and I make no changes. I simply click *Typeset* and it seems to work without error, but then I click **Build and View** and it says there is no pdf document found. Sure enough, no pdf file in that folder (named res9a.pdf, theoretically).

I am like 99.999% sure the res9a.tex file is correct since it's on this public website and furthermore, I've used it months ago to create a resume successfully. Somehow, nothing has changed, and yet, it has.

I know this is a pathetic question, but *please* please help!

Comment: Search the log-file, open it and check it for errors.

Comment: what _is_ in the folder is there a resp2.dvi ?

Comment: Nothing new is produced in the folder at all, so there's still just the three files I mentioned above. I'm presuming it's supposed to generate a log file or something? That's not there either.

Comment: Actually, I found this in the window when I typeset:line 53: /usr/texbin/pdflatex: No such file or directory

Comment: Line 53 of the .tex file is actually blank though, so I don't know what's happening there

Comment: That error usually means that your OS can't find the pdflatex executable. Have you installed a TeX distribution (TeXLive, MiKTeX etc.)?

Comment: I think this is the correct problem, I probably only re-installed TeXnicle since I got my new HDD. What do I have to do to fix this? I need to download something else?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to missing TeX distribution

Comment: I agree, this post should probably be removed. Should I just delete it or let the mods remove it or something?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @darthbith for leading me in the right direction. I was a fool, and was missing a huge piece of the puzzle I guess. MikTex for windows, I think, but I just needed to install MacTeX (http://tug.org/mactex/) and then it worked properly.